# Django - Dynamic filtering in class based views

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I am trying to write a Class Based View from an already filtered view. However I couldn't find out how to pass arguments to CBV.

I am using django 3.0.4 with pipenv python 3.8

as an example assume I have 2 models:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField()

class WorkOrder(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateField('Date', default=datetime.now)
    due_date = models.DateField('Due Date')
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Customer')
    STATUS_CHOICES = [
        ('pending', 'Pending'),
        ('approved', 'Approved'),
        ('completed', 'Completed'),
        ('cancelled', 'Cancelled'),
    ]
    status = models.CharField('Status of the work order', max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='pending')
    description = models.TextField('Description of the work')
```

I wrote a FBV for listing the work orders of a customer filtered by status. Something like that:

```
def customer_workorders(request, pk):

    customer = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=pk)
    pending_workorders = WorkOrder.objects.filter(customer=pk).filter(status='pending')
    approved_workorders = WorkOrder.objects.filter(customer=pk).filter(status='approved')
    completed_workorders = WorkOrder.objects.filter(customer=pk).filter(status='completed')
    cancelled_workorders = WorkOrder.objects.filter(customer=pk).filter(status='cancelled')

    context = {
        'customer': customer,
        'pending': pending_workorders,
        'approved': approved_workorders,
        'completed': completed_workorders,
        'cancelled': cancelled_workorders
    }

    return render(request, 'reports/cusomer_workorders.html', context)
```

I am trying to make a CBV list view of every work orders according to their status.

I know my Class Based View should be like this

```
class CustomerWorkOrderPendingView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):

    template_name = 'reports/customer_workorders_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):

        return WorkOrder.objects.filter(customer=customer).filter(status='pending')
```

My question is how can I get the customer object according to that CBV? More generally how can I pass a argument in order to make a query with it in CBV.

I know I can pass a variable like

```
{% url 'to_some_view' variable %}
```

and in FBV I can get the variable

```
def a_view(request, variable):
   some logic with variable
```

How can I do that in CBV?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who would be intrested I came up with a solution...

In my case it seems you have to do NOTHING!

The user id already passed in the url and instead of

```
return WorkOrder.objects.filter(customer=customer).filter(status='pending')
```

making a query just for status is enough.

```
return WorkOrder.objects.filter(status='pending')
```

This returns the work orders of 'The User' listed on the previous view and adds a second filter (status='pending').